# article categories - many to many with one MAIN

Tags: php, jquery, model

My client needs to select many categories for his article, but one category should act as main category.

Would it be better to model relationship as many to many and add column flag "is_main" to article_category table or use one to many for main category?

I am also trying to find some jquery widget to easilly implement function like this.

I thought about using jquery ui dragable to let him move categories between 3 divs: article main category, article regular categories and ALL CATEGORIES available in cms.

ALternatively I could use select for main category and checkboxes for the rest?

Maybe there is some ready solution?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I have checked many plugins like jquery tag-it, but none of those has option to select MAIN TAG (which is obvious).

Comment: When you say "some jQuery widget", what is it that you are hoping the widget will do for you? Basically, everything you've suggested sounds sensible, but I'm not sure how generic it would ever be. Your question also seems to be half about DB design and half about admin UI.